# How to Regex Split an expression to accept decimal number?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, split, expression

I am trying to make a calculator. I am using Regex.Split() to get the number input from the expression. It works well with non-decimal digits but now I am finding a way to get the decimal number input as well.

```cs
string mExp = "1.50 + 2.50";
string[] strNum = (Regex.Split(mExp, @"[\D+]"));
num1                = double.Parse(strNum[0]);
num2                = double.Parse(strNum[1]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your regex to split on some number of spaces followed by an arithmetic operator, followed by spaces:

```
string[] strNum = (Regex.Split(mExp, @"\s*[+/*-]\s*"));
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", strNum));
```

Output:

```
1.50
2.50
```

[Demo on rextester](https://rextester.com/OGU34752)

To deal with negative numbers, you have to make the regex a bit more sophisticated and add a lookbehind for a digit and a lookahead for either a digit or a `-`:

```
string mExp = "-1.50 + 2.50 -3.0 + -1";
string[] strNum = (Regex.Split(mExp, @"(?<=\d)\s*[+*/-]\s*(?=-|\d)"));
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", strNum));
```

Output:

```
-1.50
2.50
3.0
-1
```

[Demo on rextester](https://rextester.com/VRGQ12773)

Comment: how about if I would like to aaccept negative numbers as well?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following regex for splitting for both non-decimal and decimal numbers:

```
[^\d.]+
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cr1t98/1)

```
string[] strNum = (Regex.Split(mExp, @"[^\d.]+"));
```

Essentially saying to match anything except a digit or a dot character recursively and split by that match.